# awk or sed CSV file manipulation

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

```
"a004-1b","North","at006754"
"a004-1c","south","atytgh0"
"a004-1d","east","atrthh"
"a010-1a","midwest","atyu"
"a010-1b","south","rfg67"
```

I want to print the first column and the second column without any extra character I want eliminate all ("", and the third column) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F'^"|","|"$' '{print $2,$3}' ./infile.csv
```

The above script will even handle fields that have embedded double quotes or commas.  The only downside (if you can call it that) is that the first field starts at `$2`

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ awk -F'^"|","|"$' '{print $2,$3}' ./infile.csv
a004-1b North

a004-1c south

a010-1a midwest

a010-1b south
```

Comment: better than mine. in my defense, I almost never use awk or sed any more :^\

Comment: I must confess most of my `awk` and `sed` usage is right here on SO =)

Answer (score 2):

You need GNU Awk 4 for this to work:

```
$ gawk -vFPAT='[^",]+' '{print $1,$2}'
```

I love this new "field pattern" feature. It's my new hammer and everything is a nail. Read up on it at http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

(Written this way it doesn't account for embedded commas or quotes, because the question implies this is not needed.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it "pure" awk or sed, this won't fit the bill, but otherwise it works:

```
awk -F, '{print $1 " " $2}' | tr -d '"'
```

Comment: Although it does not handle embedded quotes or commas, the latter being not too out of ordinary in my experience (unfortunately).

Comment: yeah, well with any amount of complexity it makes sense to switch to Python or something else with built-in CSV support.

Comment: `cut -d "," -f 1,2 --output-delimiter=" "| tr -d '"'` would do the same, so awk not needed here.

Comment: @jfgagne, quite true but the OP specified awk or sed. personally I prefer cut.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `awk` for this, why put a Perl tag on it?

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

# Make Data::Dumper pretty
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent   = 1;

# Set maximum depth for Data::Dumper, zero means unlimited
local $Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = 0;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
while( my $row = $csv->getline( \*DATA )){
  print 'row: ', Dumper $row;
}

__DATA__
"a004-1b","North","at006754"
"a004-1c","south","atytgh0""a004-1d","east","atrthh"
"a010-1a","midwest","atyu"
"a010-1b","south","rfg67"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'\"|\,' '{print $2,$5}' sample
```

Comment: You don't need to escape out the quote or the comma, `awk -F'"|,'` will suffice.  But like some of the other answers, this does not work with fields that have embedded quotes or commas. Instead, use `awk -F'^"|","|"$` which takes care off all the corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not handling embedded double quotes:

```
sed -e 's/^"\([^"]*\)","\([^"]*\)".*/\1 \2/'
```

To handle them:

```
sed -n -e 's/^"//;s/"$//;s/","/ /;s/","/\n/;P'
```

The above works even for a 1 or 2 field input.