# Extract specific fields from text file

Tags: mysql, sql, awk, file-io

I have a csv file with over 5k fields/columns with header names. I would like to import only some specific fields to my database.

I am using local infile for other smaller files which need to be imported

```
LOAD DATA
LOCAL INFILE 'C:/wamp/www/imports/new_export.csv'
INTO TABLE table1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(colour,shape,size);
```

Assigning dummy variables for columns to skip might be cumbersome, Also I would prefer to reference using the fields headers to future proof in case the file has additional fields

I am considering using awk on the file before loading the file to the database. But the examples I have found in search don't seem to work.

Any suggestions on best approach for this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7095057/1468366) using `FPAT`? If that failed, how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to MvG's answer, but it doesn't require `gawk` 4 and thus uses `-F` as suggested in that answer. It also shows a technique for listing the desired fields and iterating over the list. This may make the code easier to maintain if there is a large list.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    col_list = "colour shape size" # continuing with as many as desired for output
    num_cols = split(col_list, cols)
    FS = OFS = ","
}

NR==1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        p[$i] = i # remember column for name
    }
    # next # enable this line to suppress headers.
}

{
    delim = ""
    for (i = 1; i <= num_cols; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", delim, $p[cols[i]]
        delim = OFS
    }
    printf "\n"
}
```

Comment: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1.    I am seeing syntax errors on both these scripts (yours and MvG's). I am a noob at this. I am running the code using awk script.sh data.txt

Comment: The script executes with /usr/bin/awk -f script.sh data.csv
awk: record `colour,size,shape,new,alti...' too long   I am seeing this error

Comment: @SantoshPillai: Is the error "record too long"? Does this give you an error (or what does it print)? `awk '{print length($0), $NF} NR > 2 {exit}' data.csv`

Comment: @SantoshPillai: My script is designed to be marked as executable: `chmod u+x scriptname`. To run it: `./scriptname data.csv` (substitute a name you choose without `.sh` at the end).

Comment: Figured the problem. Its my version of awk. Installed a newer version and this is working. Thanks

Comment: I am using code below, works well on a small file. For a big file takes ages to parse. Is there anything wrong with the code? out_file = "output.txt"
BEGIN {
    col_list = "name colour" # continuing with as many as desired for output
    num_cols = split(col_list, cols)
    FS = OFS = ","
}

NR==1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        p[$i] = i # remember column for name
    }
    # next # enable this line to suppress headers.
}

{
    delim = ""
    for (i = 1; i <= num_cols; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", delim, $p[cols[i]]>out_file
        delim = OFS
    }
    printf "\n">out_file
}

Comment: @SantoshPillai: How big is the file? The assignment to `out_file` should be done inside the `BEGIN` block. The way you have it now, it's being done for every line of input.

Comment: You are brilliant :) . Yes moving the out_file sorted this. It takes 2 seconds to execute a 100 mb file

Answer (score 0):

Does your actual data have any commas? If not, you might be best served using `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f1,2,5,8-12
```

will select the named fields, splitting lines at the `,`. If any of your `"`-enclosed text fields does contain a `,`, things will break, as `cut` doesn't know about `"`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the job. I don't have any commas in the data. Is there any way of doing this by specifying column header instead of column number?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full-featured solution which can deal with all kinds of quotes and commas in the values of the csv table, and can extract columns by name. It requires `gawk` and is based on the `FPAT` feature suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7095057/1468366).

```
BEGIN {
  # Allow simple values, quoted values and even doubled quotes
  FPAT="\"[^\"]*(\"\"[^\"]*)*\"|[^,]*"
}
NR==1 {
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    p[$i]=i # remember column for name
  }
  # next # enable this line to suppress headers.
}
{
  print $p["colour"] "," $p["shape"] "," $p["size"]
}
```

Write this to a file, to be invoked by `gawk -f file.awk`.

As the column-splitting and the index-by-header features are kind of orthogonal, you could use part of the script on non-GNU awk to select by column name, not using `FPAT` but simple `-F,` instead.